# PHP packing some data

Tags: php, c++

c++ struct:

```
struct Data {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
    UCHAR result;
    short Number;
    char Id[10];
    int Admin;
    int Blocked;
    char Proj[13];
};
```

I maked this with php:

```
pack("C4sc10iic13", /** **/);
```

but it's not correct. I think

Comment: Why are you messing c++ and php? Choose one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `UCHAR` means `unsigned char`, your format string could be `"CCCCsc10iic13"`.  This is very similar to yours, only splitting out `a` `b` `c` and `result` into four Cs instead of a C4.

Perhaps you can also tell us exactly what's wrong?